# Generating a skewed distribution given a size, lower bound, and upper bound

Tags: random, statistics, distribution, skew

How do you generate a skewed distribution with just the size, lower bound, and upper bound? Initially, there is no data and I think I just need to generate data randomly but after that how do you make it skewed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any asymmetric distribution is skewed, you just have to pick one and go with it.  One of the easiest choices would be to use a [triangular distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution).  If `U` is a uniformly distributed random number between 0 and 1, `low` is the lower bound, and `high` is the upper bound, you can generate random variates `X` which have a maximally left-skewed right-triangular distribution with

```
X = low + (high - low) * sqrt(U)
```

For a maximally right-skewed version

```
X = low + (high - low) * (1 - sqrt(U))
```

For a less skewed result, use the generalized triangle generation algorithm from the linked Wikipedia page.  As long as the mode of the triangle is not the mid-range value, the result will be skewed. As the mode is moved closer to either end of the range the distribution becomes more skewed